# Angular 6 change label class on radio button change

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a radio button group in my angular component like this:

```
<label class="btn-{{cl1}}">
  <input type="radio" value="am" name="time" formControlName="time1" (change)="cl1=active" >9:00am
</label>
```

I want to change the parent label class of each radio button once it is checked and remove once it is unchecked. I can use lots of variables like cl1, cl2, cl3... but is there any easy approach of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<label [class.active]="r.checked">
    <input #r type="radio" value="am" name="time" formControlName="time1">
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't think it was that easy :)